# Use of a literal "%" in a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping, character

I am trying to use the following statement:

```
sssd_conf = \
    'enumerate = true\n' \
    'ldap_default_bind_dn = %(machines_ldap_dn)s\n' \
    'ldap_default_authtok_type = password\n' \
    'ldap_default_authtok = %(ldap_password)s\n' \
    'use_fully_qualified_names = false\n' \
    'override_homedir = /home/%d/%u\n' \
    % {
        'ldap_password': self.ldap_password,
        'machines_ldap_dn': get_machines_ldap_dn(ldap_master, master_username, master_pw),
        'master_ip': master_ip
    }
```

When running the code with this variable I get `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`.

As you can see I *need* to use a literal `%` in `'override_homedir = /home/%d/%u\n'`, but python is interpreting `%d` and `%u` as variables to be placed in those locations. How can I escape the `%` in my statement?

I tried `'override_homedir = /home/\%d/\%u\n' \` but this did not work.

BTW this is python2.7 code. I inherited it and do not want to port it to 3 right now.

Comment: Have you tried `@'override_homedir = /home/%d/%u\n'`

Comment: `%%` will become just %

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that was it! thanks, feel free to answer the question and I can give points.